# Prove function $f$ is not onto

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics

Let $f: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ defined by $$f(x) = 2x^{2}+x.$$
Prove that $f$ is not onto.

The problem is, I think it IS onto because for every $y$ I try to create there's an $x$ that can make it through the function. Why am I wrong?

Comment: Try $f(x)=-1{}$.

Comment: @AmandaO there are many ways to show this, as Bernard shown you need to find at least a value such that $f(x)=a$ has not solution, or as an alternative you can show that f(x) is bounded that is has a global maximum or a global minimum, for that you can study the derivative, or completing the square or consider the limits at $\pm \infty$ and by continuity.

Comment: Thanks the graph helps me a ton. Very easy to see.

Comment: @AmandaO Yes a simple sketch can help a lot to understand the problem, then remember that any conclusion need to be formalized and made rigorous by theorems

Comment: This is easiest to see by graphing the function, or even just imagining it: It will be an upward-facing parabola.  Therefore, $y$-values that are down low on the $y$-axis have no corresponding $x$-value.

Comment: @JairTaylor Yes of course in this particular case observing that it is parabola easily leads to the solution, anyway it is useful also apply some more general method in order to can solve also more challenging problems.

Comment: @AmandaO Please remember that you can choose an answer among the given if the OP is solved, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: note that the codomain is $\mathbb{R}$. (For example: what is the preimage of $y=-42$?)

Answer (score 3):

Completing the square $2x^2+x=2(x+1/4)^2-1/8$, observe that a square is always $\geq0$. Therefore, values $<-1/8$ cannot be attained.

Answer (score 2):

**HINT**

Let consider the limit for $x\to \pm \infty$and observe that $f(x)$ is continuous.

Comment: @Bernard Thanks for the editing!

Comment: You're welcome! I was just passing by…

Comment: Thanks it did help to graph it!

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

- Try to find the minimal value that this function can attain, perhaps by completing the square or calculus.
- From the answer in the previous part, you should be able to construct a number with no preimage.

Answer (score 0):

Let $m \in \mathbb R$

If $f(x) = m$ would mean $2x^2 + x = m$ so $2x^2 + x - m = 0$ so $x =\frac {-1\pm \sqrt {1 + 8m}}{4}$.

Can that always happen?  Are there any $m$ were that can't happen?

Well, it can't happen if $1 + 8m < 0$ or $m < -\frac 18$.

And that makes sense.  The $x$ "part" of $2x^2 + x$ dips down into the negatives and can be as negative as we want,  but the $2x^2$ "part" bobs right back up into the positives and if $2x^2 > |x|$ the "positive force" of $2x^2$ overwhelms the "negative force" of $x$ and we just can't sink to those negative values.  And $2x^2$ "overpowers" $x$ fairly early.